# Find $\iiint_E (\sin^3 x+\tan y+ 6)\hspace{1mm} dV$, where $V$ is region inside $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I guess that the integral of $\sin^3 x+\tan x$ part is zero,

because I have seen many problems like these where the integral is over a symmetrical region and the functions are odd.

But I want to understand the reasoning behind the solution of such problems.

Comment: You already have everything... or are you asking about the reasoning of ''integral is zero when the region is symmetric and the function is odd?''

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva As I understand, that is exactly the question. The OP wants an explanation for that.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : I'm just not sure. The question at the end is kind of vague.

Comment: yes patrick da silva

Answer (score 0):

For an odd function, $f(x) = -f(-x)$.  So, if the region is symmetric about $x=0$, for every differential element on the positive side, there's a differential element on the negative side that exactly cancels it.  Add up all of these exactly-canceling pairs and you end up with zero.

Or put another way,

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = \int_{-a}^0 f(x) dx + \int_{0}^a f(x) dx.$$

We can rewrite the first term like this if $f(x)$ is odd:

$$\int_{-a}^0 f(x) dx = -\int_{0}^{-a} f(x) dx = -\int_{0}^{a} f(-x) (-dx) = -\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx.$$

The first operation switches the limits of integration.  The second substitutes $x \to -x$, $dx \to -dx$.  The last operation combines the negative signs and uses the fact that the function is odd.

Then,

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = -\int_{0}^a f(x) dx + \int_{0}^a f(x) dx = 0$$

if $f(x)$ is odd.  Hope that explains the reasoning for what you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the integral of the first term, $\sin^3(x)$.

Take some arbitrary $y_0$ and $z_0$ in the region, and integrate across the linear region along the $x$ line from $-A$ to $A$, where $A = \sqrt{1 - y_0^2 - z_0^2}$. Then the integral is,
$$
\int_{-A}^A \sin^3(x) dx = 0
$$
Of course you know that that linear one-dimensional integral is zero because the function is odd, thus the left side of the integral is the negative of the right side.

The full region integral is the sum of these line where the values of $y_0$ and $z_0$ in $A$ cover the entire circle $y_0^2 + z_0^2 = 1$, i.e.
$$
\iiint_E \sin^3(x) dx = \iint_e \int_{-A}^A \sin^3(x) dx
$$
where the region $e$ is inside the circle $y_0^2 + z_0^2 = 1$. However, since you already know that the linear integral is $0$ independent of $y_0$ and $z_0$, then the entire integral is zero, regardless of the region $e$.

The same logic applies to the $\tan(y)$ part.